# Find $n$ and $a1$ of geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

$$r = \frac{3}{4} \qquad an = \frac{27}{4} \qquad Sn = 43.75 \qquad $$
Find $n$ and $a\tiny{1} $ of G.P

I tried with the $Sn$ formula but it takes so much time and I am not going to the answer,in the end, I have to put numbers in n from 2, to get the right answer,and it is too much work for this kind of problem.

Comment: Hint: $S_n=a_1(1+r+\cdots+r^{n-1})=a_n(1+\frac 1r+\cdots+\frac 1{r^{n-1}})$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ are in geometric progression with common ratio $r$. Then from the end, the sequence
$$a_n, a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_2, a_1$$

is also a geometric progression with common ratio $1/r$.

So treat $27/4$ as first term, $4/3$ as common ratio and given sum is $175/4$. Now apply the usual sum formula
$$\frac{175}{4} = \frac{27}{4}\times \frac{(4/3)^n-1}{(4/3)-1}$$

to compute $n$. Then you can also find $a_1$ as last term of our new sequence.
$$a_1 = \frac{27}{4} \times \Big( \frac{4}{3} \Big)^{n-1}$$